# Proving Inequality Over Reals

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

If $a,b$ and $c$ are real numbers, then

$\dfrac{a+b-c}{kc^2+a^2+b^2}+\dfrac{b+c-a}{ka^2+b^2+c^2}+\dfrac{c+a-b}{kb^2+c^2+a^2}\leqslant \dfrac{9}{(k+2)(a+b+c)}$where $(k=\dfrac{3+\sqrt{17}}{4})$

My Proof

CHEBYSHEV

$(kc^2+a^2+b^2) \geq \frac{(k+1+1)(a^2+b^2+c^2)}{3}$
$\sum{\frac{a+b-c}{kc^2+a^2+b^2} }\leq {\frac{3a+3b+3c}{(k+2)(a^2+b^2+c^2)}}$

CS

$(a^2+b^2+c^2)*3 \geq (a+b+c)^2$

$\sum{\frac{a+b-c}{kc^2+a^2+b^2} }\leq {\frac{3a+3b+3c}{(k+2)(a^2+b^2+c^2)}}\leq \frac{9}{(k+2)(a+b+c)}$

hold for $(0,R+,R+),(0,0,R+),(R+,R+R+)$ and its perms

where R+ = real positive

could someone help me over reals with buffalo way,uvw, or any other inequalities
ADDITION FROM AUTHOR
$a+b+c>0$